# Can we use metatheory of set theory for proof statements in set theory?

Tags: set-theory, proof-theory, meta-math, metalogic

I wanna know if is possible or have examples of theorems in set theory, for example $\beta$, that have a demonstration of forme 
$Cons(ZFC)\Rightarrow \beta$
but $\beta$ is independent of axioms of $ZFC$.

Comment: I was thinking in sentences in language of sets, β in this case talk about sets, Con(ZFC) talk about sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You can add $Con(ZFC)$ as an assumption.  If you then derive $\beta$ you have proven within $ZFC$ that $Con(ZFC)\implies \beta$.  If you can then prove that $\beta$ is not provable from $ZFC$ you are there.

A trivial example is to take $\beta = Con(ZFC)$.  Then ordinary logic proves $Con(ZFC) \implies \beta$ even without $ZFC$.

Comment: Con(ZFC) is not independent of ZFC (or at least the statement that it is is of higher consistency strength than ZFC itself).

Comment: Statement is independent of theory iff theory can't neither prove nor disprove it. $ZFC$ can't prove (and of course can'd disprove) $Con(ZFC)$.

Comment: @mihaild “of course can’t disprove” No. it is a logical possibility that ZFC can disprove Con(ZFC). Of course it will do so if it is inconsistent, but it is even a possibility that it does so while still being consistent. ZFC could consistent, but wrong about some arithmetic statements.

Comment: I was thinking in sentences in language of sets, β in this case talk about sets, Con(ZFC) talk about sentences, but I understand your point

Comment: @AndersonBot Statements about sentences, suitably translated, are statements about sets. I.e. Con(ZFC) can be expressed in the language of set theory.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen you mean ZFC is consistent, but has only non-standard models?

Comment: @mihaild yes, that’s exactly what I mean. (It even sounds more plausible to me that way.) Actually slightly stronger: ZFC has no models with standard $\omega.$